# Use of JavaScript in lieu of hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, html

As RIAs and SPAs (or web apps with heavy javascript usage) have become more and more popular, I've been running into systems that, instead of using good old `a href` hyperlinks, I see them utilizing constructs using `onclick` with JavaScript code that manipulates navigation. This is particularly true with images.

For example, instead of seeing something like this:

```
<a href="some_url"><img src="...."/></a>

<div ... onclick='SomeJsFunctionThatNavsToAnotherPage()'><img src="..."/></a>
```

What is the advantage of this? It makes it incredibly hard to trace where pages transition to when debugging or trying to root cause a bug. I can get the idea when the target to navigate can change (so yes, here you could use a function that computes to what page to navigate to.)

But I see this pattern even when the pages to navigate to are constant. I find this extremely convoluted and hard to test. Not to mention that there is always the browser-specific bugs that come from stuff (sadly in my experience from over-complexifying the front-end.)

But I am not a RIA/SPA developer (just backend and traditional web development). ***Am I missing the rationale behind this?***

---

## TO CLARIFY

My question is not for the case when we want to redraw the page or change current content without changing the current location. My question is for plain
old transitions, from page A to page B.

In such a case, why use `onclick=funcToChangeLocation()` over `<a href="some location"/>`.

This has been a pain for me when troubleshooting systems *that are already written* (for I wouldn't write them like that), but there could be reasons I am not aware of.

Again, my question is not for pages that redraw themselves without changing the browser location, but for navigation from one page to the next.

---

## ALSO

If you are going to vote to close this question, at least leave a message explaining why.

Comment: Using divs with click handlers instead of anchors is bad practice because it makes the functionality inaccessible to keyboard-only users. (It is OK to use anchors with click handlers to navigate to some computed destination.)

Comment: Fair enough. But when you know the destination is static in most of the cases, and when the only function of anchors in a page is to simply transition to another one (with no side effect) what is the benefit of using anchors with click handlers instead of anchors with plain hrefs?

Comment: If the click handler doesn't add anything beyond what a plain anchor could've done then I don't see any point at all.

Comment: P.S. Regarding the close vote, the reason that voter chose is that answers to this question will be primarily opinion-based (Stack Overflow discourages opinion-oriented questions). I didn't vote on this question, but when I do vote to close questions I don't leave a comment about it because if a question actually does close the reason the majority of voters chose will be displayed automatically. (Though sometimes I think a question should be closed for a different reason than what the majority chose.)

Comment: Well, unless one is talking about strict mathematical constructs, most decisions in software design will be based on opinions backed by some type of empirical evidence. I could see why my question could engender opinion-based questions. But therein lies my dilemma - I cannot find any reasonable explanation for something that is having a negative effect in my line of work. But I'm not well versed enough in the domain (heavy JS web design) to know if I'm seeing an anti-pattern or if there are actual technical reasons that I'm ignorant about.

Comment: @nnnnnn is right though, this is a subjective question and a "right" answer can't be assigned. Stackoverflow is meant for posting code you need help with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are making a web application, sometime you don't want to redirect the user to another page, but you want to dynamically change the content of the page without refreshing the page. It has some advantages. It can be faster. You can easily keep the state of the page/application. You are not obligated to communicate with the server. You can update only a part of the page.

You can also dynamically request data to print the page. If you are displaying an user profile page, you can only ask a json object that represent the user. This json object is smaller than the whole page and will be dynamically rendered. It can help to reduce the data transfer between users and server when your bandwidth is limited.

EDIT: In the case of a simple page redirection, I think it's a bad practice and I cannot see an advantage. I think it obfuscate the website when the google crawler try to parse the website.

Comment: I understand the usage you are describing where the content is redraw dynamically without changing the current page. My question is for simple navigation; go from page A to page B. Why use `onclick` with a function instead of `a href`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I once had a pretty successful web directory website. One day Google decided that "directories" are competing businesses and started penalizing sites that had links on directories. I used the method you describe to cloak outgoing links to try and trick Google.

Comment: I could see this as a legitimate usage. But my question is for internal apps which are not going to be indexed by google, for example.

Comment: The only reason I could think is if you wanted to hide the URL in the statusbar on mouseover.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that. That could be a legitimate requirement. Thanks.